# I cannot figure out why my useEffect function is running twice in my NextJs client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a NextJs program and a function I use on my site called useAsync. For some reason this function runs twice every time it is called. I think it has something to do with with the useEffect calling the useAsyncInternal, but am not sure.

Here is my useAsync.tsx:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useUser from "./useUser";

export const useAsync = (func: Function, dependencies = [], requireAuth = true) => {
    const { execute, ...state } = useAsyncInternal(func, dependencies, true);
    const user = useUser();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (requireAuth) {
            if (user.id) execute();
        } else {
            execute();
        }
    }, [execute, user.id]);

    return state;
}

const useAsyncInternal = (func: Function, dependencies = [], initialLoading = false) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(initialLoading);
    const [error, setError] = useState<any>();
    const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

    const execute = useCallback((...params: any[]) => {
        setLoading(true);

        return func(...params).then((data: any) => {
            setData(data);
            setError(undefined);
            return data;
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            setData(undefined);
            setError(error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, dependencies);

    return { loading, error, data, execute }
}
```

Here is an example of calling useAsync insde of a JSX:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useAsync(myCommunities);
```

Here is the myCommunities function just in case:

```
export const myCommunities = () => {
  return request.get("/communities/my");
};
```

Comment: Do you use strict mode?

Comment: I do use reactStrictMode. I switched it off and it fixed it. Got any tips for how to fix this?

Comment: I tried to run it in production mode and it still had the error. Outside of using a useMemo I don't see a good fix. Is that the suggested fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `useEffect` has already been called

```
export const useAsync = (
  func: Function,
  dependencies = [],
  requireAuth = true
) => {
  const { execute, ...state } = useAsyncInternal(func, dependencies, true);
  const hasBeenCalledRef = useRef(false);
  const user = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasBeenCalledRef.current) return;
    hasBeenCalledRef.current = true;
    if (requireAuth) {
      if (user.id) execute();
    } else {
      execute();
    }
  }, [execute, user.id]);

  return state;
};
```

Comment: This is literally what gpt 4 said to do...

Comment: @rockets4all this site will probably be down in 10 years because of AI :)

Answer (score -1):

can use `useMemo`

```
const { execute, ...state } = useMemo(() => {
  return useAsyncInternal(func, dependencies, true);
}, dependencies);
```

it's possible that the useEffect hook is being called twice due to changes in dependencies. To prevent this, you could try wrapping the useAsyncInternal function in a useMemo hook to ensure that it's only called once.

Comment: It won't let me call useAsyncInternal from within a react hook. Here is the error.
<code>React Hook "useAsyncInternal" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const useAsyncInternal: (func: Function, dependencies?: never[], initialLoading?: boolean) => {
    loading: boolean;
    error: any;
    data: any;
    execute: (...params: any[]) => any;
}</code>